# I see the CAPTCHA when I answer to my questions

Tags: support, status-completed, captcha, answers

I answered to my two of my own questions on http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com, and in both the cases the CAPTCHA appeared. I was not editing the same answer twice in row; I was answering two different questions with a CW answer, and passed 4 minutes between an answer and the other, as I was looking for any questions without an answer, to avoid Community would bump the questions. I am a moderator on *Drupal Answers*, and the questions to which I added an answer are both listed in [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).

After 19 minutes (see [my activity on meta.drupal.SE](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/199/kiamlaluno?tab=activity)), I then added a second answer to the question asked by another user (on the same meta site), and also in that case the CAPTCHA appeared.
I also edited one of the previous answers I gave (just few minutes ago), and the CAPTCHA was not shown.

Is this normal?

Comment: I think I always see the captcha when I answer my own question, even on metas.

Comment: It happened I added an answer to my own questions, before, but I have never seen the CAPTCHA.

Comment: Answering your own questions sounds like suspicious behavior to me.

Comment: @Tobias Cohen It's the site where I am a moderator; We were asked to take care of those questions in the meta site without any answer, and considering that the questions were those that are listed in [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), I added an answer to those questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this normal?

Nope, it's not :)

This was a typo that caused one of the spam prevention mechanisms to fail for self-answers, and a failing spam prevention mechanism means you get a captcha.

This is fixed in the next build.

Answer (score 0):

Has it shown up every time you posted something?

Usually the CAPTCHA shows up if your post rate is higher than a certain threshold. I don't know the exact threshold, but even I've gotten it a couple of times when I answer questions quickly so I'm assuming it's in the range of a couple of minutes.

Comment: I don't frequently ask question on that meta site, or even answer to questions (for the simple fact there are few users asking questions). I think those were the first two answers I provided on that site.

Comment: I checked, and I have answered to the second question 4 minutes later than when I answered to the first question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno hmm, we'll have to wait till someone with more knowledge on the limit looks at this. But it's not unexpected, all users run into captcha

Comment: It is only unexpected that I would see the CAPTCHA in those cases.